# Minimal Free resolution of the ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, syzygies

What is the motivation to study the *minimal free resolution* of the ideals? Which geometrical information can we get from $res(I)$ for The variety of $I$?

Answer (score 5):

The most basic motivation for studying resolutions is computing the Hilbert function/polynomial of $Y=V(I)$. The geometric information in this polynomial is essentially the dimension, the embedded degree of $Y$ and the arithmetic genus of $Y$.

More refined information can be found by looking at the betti numbers of $I$. By definition, these are the ranks of the free modules appearing in the resolution and thus tell us about the *syzygies* of $I$, that is, the relations between the generators of $I$. A standard example (see Eisenbud's book) is the case of 7 points in $\mathbb{P}^3$: All such configurations of points have the same Hilbert polynomial, but the graded Betti numbers of the ideal of the points determine whether the points lie on a rational normal curve or not.

For curves, there are also interesting relations between the betti numbers of a canonically embedded curve and the Clifford index of the curve (which is a geometrical invariant of the curve). This is the main content of Green's conjecture, which is still open.

For more info on this, take a look at Eisenbud's excellent book 'The Geometry of Syzygies' or Wiegand's article '[What is.. a Syzygy](http://www.ams.org/notices/200604/what-is.pdf)?'